# Process.StartInfo clarifications c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, kill

I'm trying to run another process from the main one using Process class.

```
AudioRecordProcess = new Process();
AudioRecordProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
AudioRecordProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"RecordAudio\RecordAudio";
AudioRecordProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

The process starts fine but:

- Even if I set CreateNoWindow property when I run the code a window is created (the other process is a WPF project with just the main window);
- When I try to close the process with closemainwindow it does close nothing. The window just goes under the main process' one.
- If I try to kill the process from code it doesn't execute the instructions in my event closing main window, but if I close it from the taskbar it executes that routine. Shouldn't the actions be the same?

Any idea for this strange behavior?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you run! while the show no window is passed to the run command the app (while it should) doesnt have to honor it for any other windows it feels like throwing up

Comment: Can you better explain. I understood that it can not work for every type of program so I should assume that WPF is not compatible with nowindow option. I didn't understand "doesn't have to honor it for any other windows it feels like throwing up". What about the closing part?

Comment: any process you spawn can and will do whatever it likes .. and depending on the app, you may have spawned a process but unless you specifically end that process shutting your app wont terminate it

Answer (score 0):

Class 'Process' is used to create and/or control and monitor specific process.

- Only console application will obey CreateNoWindow = true, while
  Windows Forms and WPF applications will ignore it.
- Since you have started another process on the system, that process
  will continue on its own and will not be terminated once you stop
  parent process. However there are some resource lingering (especially
  thread and handle related) in the parent process which prevents
  parent process termination when its main window is closed.
- killing interrupts normal process execution and forces stop as soon
  as possible therefore it is normal that closing handlers are not
  executed

**EDIT:**

For test create WPF application and put following code in it:

```
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        Closed += MainWindow_Closed;
    }

    private Process process;

    private void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Log("WpfApp3.log", $"{DateTime.Now} Closed");
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Log("WpfApplication3.log", $"{DateTime.Now} Loaded");
        process = new Process {
            StartInfo = {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                // FileName = @"..\..\WpfApp2\bin\Debug\WpfApp2.exe",
                FileName = @"..\..\CnslApp1\bin\Debug\CnslApp1.exe",
                // FileName = @"..\..\WnFrmApp2\bin\Debug\WnFrmApp2.exe",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        var result = process.CloseMainWindow();
        if (result) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Then create three new projects; one for each of Console/Windows Forms/WPF. and enter correct path to the executable into 'FileName' paramter of the StartInfo. Then you can play with parameters to see how each will behave.

In my case, process.CloseMainWindow() did had no effect until was moved into another method because process was not started yet. But once moved into a button handler and executed it will terminate all three types (one can be used at the time with this example).

Sole exception was Console application when window was hidden.

Comment: Everything clear except the second point. If I spawn a process I do not understand why Process.CloseMainWindow shouldn't work. Isn't it like pressing the x button?

Comment: @Alex, method CloseMainWindow will close 'main window' of WindowsForm and WPF application but not of ConsoleApp because CreateNoWindow is set to true.  
  
Only reason (beside pointed parameter) for an app not to close will be any background thread which is still active.  
  
You are doing something in background which is preventing app to close.

Comment: @Alex, which window you are closing with 'CloseMainWindow' (parent process window or child)?

Comment: @Alex, also do not forget timing,
if you did something like  
process.Start();  
process.CloseMainWindow();  
then you risk no to send message (check return result of last method) due to fact that newly started app does not have window ready.

Comment: "CloseMainWindow will close 'main window' of WindowsForm and WPF application but not of ConsoleApp". I think that's the opposite. It's clear that if I set createnowindow I cannot use closemainwindow. Anyway I switched the output type of my project to console application so that when I start the process I don't see the standard WPF window but the console one. In this way closemainwindow do close the process.

Comment: I close the child process window and there is no timing problem I start the process and after a while I close it

Comment: Added code is used to test this behavior (see EDIT) and with it given description is true. Let me know if it behaves differently for you.

Comment: Actually your example works, I don't why when moving to my solution the child window is not closed